# Delete used lines or don't use them again

Tags: php

this code works with the plugin that shares on social media, but it doesn't work as I want, I want to delete the lines after using and sending them.How else can I do this? can you edit it according to the code below? may be in a different arrangement

codes:

```
$fileNames = 'file1.txt';
$lines = file($fileNames, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$randomLineKey = array_rand($lines);
$randomLine = $lines[$randomLineKey];
unset($lines[$randomLineKey]);
$bom = "http://example,com/".$randomLine;
$get_link = wp_get_link("$bom/".$post_id, $post->post_content);
```

this is how he shares:

```
http://example.com/Lemon
http://example.com/Banana
http://example.com/Apple
```

file1,txt content: before

```
Lemon
Banana
Apple
```

I want the row used to be deleted after posting to social media:

```
http://example.com/Lemon
```

file1,txt content: after

```
Banana
Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the `$lines` back to the file.

```php
// after your code
file_put_contents('file1.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

Comment: didn't work still doesn't delete rows

Comment: Before `file_put_contents()` dump the variable `$lines` to see what's inside.